# Angular CLI : dist not working

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular project, its working with `ng serve`, but when I created build using `ng build --prod` , and run that on HTTP server, it is giving error - appConfig not found, whereas it is defined in a file.

Comment: Please add fully error log

Comment: error in browser console -

Comment: main.0367326….bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: appConfig is not defined
    at Object.9LK0 (main.0367326….bundle.js:1)
    at r (inline.659fffe….bundle.js:1)
    at Object.B0wd (main.0367326….bundle.js:1)
    at r (inline.659fffe….bundle.js:1)
    at Object.r84I (main.0367326….bundle.js:1)
    at r (inline.659fffe….bundle.js:1)
    at Object.PqLd (main.0367326….bundle.js:1)
    at r (inline.659fffe….bundle.js:1)
    at Object.kke6 (main.0367326….bundle.js:1)
    at r (inline.659fffe….bundle.js:1)

Comment: Post your index.html code

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body style="background:#e0e0e0">
  <tq-app>
    <div style="padding: 20%;text-align:center;">
      <h3>LOADING...</h3>
    </div>
  </tq-app>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script>
    if (!appConfig) {
      console.warn('Missing config.js file!');
    }
  </script>
</body>

Comment: actually when i run dist on local http server its working but not on remote server

Comment: Take a look into your base URL.

Comment: what is wrong in base url ?